# How do you make (NSString*)text work with NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, string, sdk, nstimer

I can't use pokeme:@"1" or pokeme:1 or pokeme:"sdfsdfs" on NSTimer.
 I have error appear.  How do you fix this?

```
- (void)Anything {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:06.00f target:self selector:@selector(Pokeme:@"1") userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)Pokeme:(NSString *)text {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that — a selector is just the *name* of a method, and the argument to that method will be the timer. You'll have to either create a new method that contains the behavior you want and pass *that* as the selector or use something like [NSTimer+Blocks](https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling a selector correctly, nor are you taking the correct arguments on -Pokeme:.

1. You need to call the selector with @selector(Pokeme:)
2. -PokeMe: needs to take the timer as the argument (I suggest you read the [NSTimer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) again).
3. Be sure to use the userInfo to pass any data you need in -Pokeme:

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid selector. A selector is just the <strike>method signature</strike> method's name, you cannot pass it parameters therefore you should have

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.00f target:self selector:@selector(pokeMe:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

According to the [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) docs the signature of the receiving method should be off the form

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer
```

So you should define your method as

```
- (void)pokeMe:(NSTimer *)timer;
```

If you want to pass extra information along the `userInfo` argument accepts a type of `id` and can be retrieved from the `timer` object.

A working example would be

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:06.00f target:self selector:@selector(pokeMe:) userInfo:@"I was passed" repeats:NO];
```

then

```
- (void)pokeMe:(NSTimer *)timer;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", timer.userInfo);
}

#=> 2012-05-03 00:57:40.496 Example[3964:f803] I was passed
```

Comment: Kind of a nitpick, but a selector is a method's *name* — a method's signature is represented by NSMethodSignature.

Comment: @Chuck I don't think improving someone's knowledge and correcting an error is "nitpicking". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the [`NSTimer Class Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

This is not the correct way to pass a variable and in fact will throw the compiler. Use **`userInfo`** to pass an object, then you can convert that object to `NSString` or whatever you need.

```
/* INCORRECT */
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:06.00f target:self 
                        selector:@selector(Pokeme:@"1") userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Basically, `userInfo` can be an object:

### NSString

```
/* Pass @"1" as the userInfo object. */
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self 
                           selector:@selector(Pokeme:) userInfo:@"1" repeats:NO];

/* Convert the object to NSString. */
-(void)Pokeme:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSString *passedString = (NSString*)timer.userInfo;
}
```

### NSDictionary

```
/* Create an NSDictionary with 2 Key/Value objects. */
NSDictionary *passTheseKeys = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Some String Value 1", @"StringKey1", 
                                   @"Some String Value 2", @"StringKey2", nil];

/* Pass the NSDictionary we created above. */
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self 
                  selector:@selector(Pokeme:) userInfo:passTheseKeys repeats:NO];

/* Convert the timer object to NSDictionary and handle it in the usual way. */
- (void)Pokeme:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSDictionary *passed = (NSDictionary *)[timer userInfo];
    NSString * objectString1 = [passed objectForKey:@"StringKey1"];
    NSString * objectString2 = [passed objectForKey:@"StringKey2"];
}
```